# RTP library for Android

Tags: java, android, rtp

I am looking for an RTP lirbary for Android. So far I could not find any. Is there any such library?

Alternatively, I think I can use any RTP library for JSE for which I can get the source code. I can compile the code in Android. I will be writing a proprietary application so the license has to permit that. Can anyone suggest a library meeting my criteria?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support RTP as a standard you will have to use a JAVA RTP library.

Android uses a subset of the Java libraries so is not full Java with this in mind it is unlikely that the SCTP support will be implemented natively in Android

Answer (score 0):

You can use JRTPLIB for Android as native library.

see below Link...

http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib